# Hibernate inner differences between generator sequence and assigned for id = 0

Tags: java, hibernate, generator

There is something in the inner hibernate's behavior I don't understand.

I have got a *normal* hibernate configuration of a class having an other one in reference.

My principal class below

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.my.package">

        <class name="MyClass" table="MY_TABLE">
            <id name="id" column="ID">
                <generator class="sequence">
                    <param name="sequence">SEQ_MY_TABLE</param>
                </generator>
            </id>
            <!-- reference -->
            <many-to-one class="MyReferenceClass" fetch="select" name="myReference">
                <column name="ID" not-null="true"/>
            </many-to-one>
            <!-- some other properties ... -->
            .
            .
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And the reference class below

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.my.package">
    <class name="MyReferenceClass" table="MY_REFERENCE_CLASS">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
            <generator class="sequence" />
        </id>
    </class>

    <!-- Some propeties -->
    .
    .

</hibernate-mapping>
```

I have in this table of reference some lines:
id , property1, property2
0    val1x  val2x
1    val1y  val2y
2    val1z  val2z
.
.

My problem is that when I try to insert a new instance of MyClass having a reference to MyReferenceClass with id 1,2,..., I have no problem. But when I try to insert one with the id = 0, I have got the exception below:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.my.package.MyClass.myReference
    at org.hibernate.engine.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:290)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:507)
```

I resolved the problematic by changing the generator class from sequence to assigned in the MyReferenceClass.hbm.xml :

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.my.package">
        <class name="MyReferenceClass" table="MY_REFERENCE_CLASS">
            <id name="id" type="long">
                <column name="ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
                <generator class="assigned" />
            </id>
        </class>

        <!-- Some propeties -->
        .
        .

</hibernate-mapping>
```

The problem is that I have no clue why it doesn't work only when my id = 0 and not every time.

Which mecanism do I not understand in this part of the Hibernate Framework ?

PS: I know that the sequence in my first file is false as we have no sequence here, that's actually an old legacy code I'm making evolve, but I don't understand why it worked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the unsaved-value attribute of the id mapping for the MyReferenceClass is defaulting to 0, and cascading updates aren't enabled for MyClass.

When you add an object with an id other than the unsaved-value Hibernate assumes you're referencing an existing row. When you add an object with an id matching the unsaved-value then Hibernate assumes the entity is transient and needs to be persisted in order to get a new value from the sequence. And because your collection isn't cascading, Hibernate assumes the references are to existing, non-transient entities.

Changing the generator to "assigned" means you assume full responsibility for populating the id and Hibernate won't have to worry about it.

To make this work with the sequence generator you could save the objects before you add them to the collection, or set up a cascade on the mapping for the collection.

Comment: Ok ! I was totally not aware of this unsaved-value attribute, but it makes more sense now. Thanks for your answer.